# Div Border and Positioning

Tags: html, css

I've created a div that contains a grid layout, but the border doesn't surround it correctly, unless I manually set its height. I've included a snippet [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4aqdjm0e/). I'm not sure why it gets cut off early, and I've also noticed that if I comment out the `portrait-crop` class, it gets cut off even further up. I'd also like to display the "Photos by..." text below the grid, but it's currently defaulting [above it](http://www.mtscollective.com/2014/10/gallery-senses-fail-no-bragging-rights_52.html).

This is the basic HTML:

```
<div class="post-content">
<div class="gallery">
<a href="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rr2z22v0QgY/VDKGa9ovtnI/AAAAAAAAWbY/CXRKfU6WPcU/s1024/01-kp.jpg"><img class="left-half" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rr2z22v0QgY/VDKGa9ovtnI/AAAAAAAAWbY/CXRKfU6WPcU/s319/01-kp.jpg"></a><a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OAiF-OjYJzA/VDKGa4axmDI/AAAAAAAAWbc/vmoLHWz86zI/s1024/02-kp.jpg"><img class="right-half" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OAiF-OjYJzA/VDKGa4axmDI/AAAAAAAAWbc/vmoLHWz86zI/s319/02-kp.jpg"></a>

<a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6IYhW-Ksbm8/VDKGaVkLJAI/AAAAAAAAWbQ/FJUbM4S2kMk/s1014/03-kp.jpg"><img class="left-half" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6IYhW-Ksbm8/VDKGaVkLJAI/AAAAAAAAWbQ/FJUbM4S2kMk/s319/03-kp.jpg"></a><a href="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-uy9eVashTA0/VDKGfXqlExI/AAAAAAAAWbk/oGtEW4zcW-U/s1024/04-ttw.jpg"><img class="right-half" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-uy9eVashTA0/VDKGfXqlExI/AAAAAAAAWbk/oGtEW4zcW-U/s319/04-ttw.jpg"></a>

<a href="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-wBlWTyzJq-M/VDKGgTEIJCI/AAAAAAAAWbs/4Qv6TLd6AT8/s1024/05-ttw.jpg"><img class="left-half" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-wBlWTyzJq-M/VDKGgTEIJCI/AAAAAAAAWbs/4Qv6TLd6AT8/s319/05-ttw.jpg"></a><a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-vD0o2eYgybU/VDKGhX2HaoI/AAAAAAAAWb0/ZxLh_Q4FlJE/s1024/06-ttw.jpg"><img class="right-half" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-vD0o2eYgybU/VDKGhX2HaoI/AAAAAAAAWb0/ZxLh_Q4FlJE/s319/06-ttw.jpg"></a>

<a href="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-HU1ZzV4myDI/VDKGimDTPgI/AAAAAAAAWb8/93BOoWrs9KY/s1024/07-nbr.jpg"><img class="left-half" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-HU1ZzV4myDI/VDKGimDTPgI/AAAAAAAAWb8/93BOoWrs9KY/s319/07-nbr.jpg"></a><div class="portrait-crop"><a href="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-O3cyqF3Gu5U/VDKGqr9xkeI/AAAAAAAAWcU/TRu0oBIgk80/s1024/08-nbr.jpg"><img class="right-half" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-O3cyqF3Gu5U/VDKGqr9xkeI/AAAAAAAAWcU/TRu0oBIgk80/s467/08-nbr.jpg"></a></div>

<a href="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-OowRDQw86lA/VDKGmrQLK2I/AAAAAAAAWcE/orAgQ6ksV7A/s1024/09-nbr.jpg"><img class="left-half" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-OowRDQw86lA/VDKGmrQLK2I/AAAAAAAAWcE/orAgQ6ksV7A/s319/09-nbr.jpg"></a><a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-zddd5Vn1fh4/VDKGnvMCMyI/AAAAAAAAWcM/rizq8xatHaM/s1024/10-nbr.jpg"><img class="right-half" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-zddd5Vn1fh4/VDKGnvMCMyI/AAAAAAAAWcM/rizq8xatHaM/s319/10-nbr.jpg"></a>

<a href="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-mwe97_lv3_E/VDKGsSzSreI/AAAAAAAAWcg/9bZ9k50Tuac/s1024/11-sf.jpg"><img class="left-half" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-mwe97_lv3_E/VDKGsSzSreI/AAAAAAAAWcg/9bZ9k50Tuac/s319/11-sf.jpg"></a><a href="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-jOCp7Ho5ZZU/VDKGsiyZbwI/AAAAAAAAWck/KxMnVKfjEPw/s1024/12-sf.jpg"><img class="right-half" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-jOCp7Ho5ZZU/VDKGsiyZbwI/AAAAAAAAWck/KxMnVKfjEPw/s319/12-sf.jpg"></a>

<a href="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-1zKhsQ8tRzY/VDKGvPI60yI/AAAAAAAAWcs/rmDBhOdZvyU/s1024/13-sf.jpg"><img class="left-half" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-1zKhsQ8tRzY/VDKGvPI60yI/AAAAAAAAWcs/rmDBhOdZvyU/s319/13-sf.jpg"></a><a href="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-8nB7X8FMihk/VDKGw5zC2qI/AAAAAAAAWc4/np_RIf5Qk-Q/s1024/14-sf.jpg"><img class="right-half" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-8nB7X8FMihk/VDKGw5zC2qI/AAAAAAAAWc4/np_RIf5Qk-Q/s319/14-sf.jpg"></a>

<a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-bHrL50qcEV0/VDKGxZojWzI/AAAAAAAAWc8/jnmwCrJfzYc/s1024/15-sf.jpg"><img class="left-half" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-bHrL50qcEV0/VDKGxZojWzI/AAAAAAAAWc8/jnmwCrJfzYc/s319/15-sf.jpg"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Adding `overflow: auto` to `.gallery` solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.gallery {
     overflow: auto;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4aqdjm0e/1/)**